# $concat mongo not working

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

Using $project operator and want to concatenate two fields result and one string to them.

```
  'check_concat'=>array('$concat'=>'$pickup_delivery_date_and_time_to','cheema'),
```

giving output as an exception

```
127.0.0.1:27017: exception: this object is already an operator expression, and can't be used as a document expression (at '0')
```

Comment: This may help you with the exact notations to used.https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/

Answer (score 0):

You should use double quotes:

```
'check_concat' => array("$concat"=>"$pickup_delivery_date_and_time_to",'cheema'),
```

[What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax follows, for example:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { 
        "$project": { 
            "check_concat": { 
                "$concat": ["$pickup_delivery_date_and_time_to", "cheema"] 
            } 
        } 
    }
])
```

in PHP, this translate to

```
<?php
$m = new MongoClient("localhost");
$c = $m->selectDB("test")->selectCollection("collection");
$ops = array(
    array(
        "$project" => array(
            "check_concat" => array(                
                "$concat" => array("$pickup_delivery_date_and_time_to", "cheema")
            )
        )
    )
);
$results = $c->aggregate($ops);
var_dump($results);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks @chridam Its working now according to your example .Cheers Thanks a lot.